# Forecasting Extreme values

Tags: regression, forecasting

I am attempting to forecast "peak" values. I have a weekly data set ~10 years. I have weather metrics as explanatory variables. I am trying to produce a model that can accurately predict the peaks of the weekly data using the weather metrics. The peaks are not entirely accurate, should I be using another approach? I am currently using MLR. Pred vs actual shows good explanatory ability until you reach more extreme observations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the power to comment, so I answer.

If the model has a "radius of convergence" outside of which its predictive ability is essentially meaningless then I would infer that there is a second model that is not informed by your current data, that governs in that extreme range.

Questions whose answers might be useful include:

- what is the exact edge of the "convergence range"?
- Can you find explanatory variables that indicate smaller but specific and accurate variations in the edge of the range?
- Is the sampling once per week too sparse?  Is the under-sampling causing the misinformation.

You can go to places like weather underground and get hour-by-hour weather for particular locations.  You might compare the predictive power of weekly data with the predictive power of daily data.  If the daily data gives substantially better results then at least part of your problem is undersampling.  You might also consider adjacent geographies.  When a storm hits down, it first had to go through another place first.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for this. The weekly data was averaged up from daily samples. How does one discover the radius of convergence?

Comment: There is going to be an inflection point in your pred vs. actual as a function or extremity of observation.  That is your "radius".

Try averaging into half-weeks and re-perform analysis, and then look at the inflection where the error starts "exploding".  This will give you a gross reality check (GRC) about whether you are undersampling.